# Keyboard language for Blender is different from the keyboard language in other applications

Tags: text-object, text-editor

I've encountered a very weird 'feature'...

When I type into text boxes in Blender, it has a different keyboard language layout than my usual one in all other applications on my laptop. (I have a full numpad keyboard, so emulate numpad is not turned on.)

To clarify:

- When I press 'shift' and the key to the right of my zero key (0) on my keyboard I usually get the underscore (_). In other words, in all other applications:

  > shift+- results in _
- When I press the same button combination in Blender I get the equals sign (=). So in Blender that's:

  > shift+- results in =

I use the Windows 10 'English (India)' layout, and it functions consistently across all other applications, e.g. this website in Chrome, MS Word, Photoshop, Flash, etc. It is only in Blender where the keyboard input doesn't match the output on the screen.

This happens everywhere you can type into the editor as far as I can tell: e.g. the text editor, asset panels, user preferences search box, etc. I first noticed it because it started breaking my naming conventions that use underscores.

Is this is known thing? Is there a way to set Blender to use the same keyboard layout for text input as my other applications?

(Sorry about the vague tags on this question, there didn't seem many appropriate.)

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me. Are the letters in the layout you use in the same position than in standard qwerty (afaik. this https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3a/Qwerty.svg/2000px-Qwerty.svg.png)? If not, do letters show up the right way?

Comment: And do the special characters match the image I linked?

Comment: This looks related: http://blenderartists.org/forum/archive/index.php/t-96486.html

Comment: Look in the tray area of your windows desktop (the lower right area where you also can find the clock) There you can find the language indicator icon. Does it change when Blender is the active application?

Comment: Today it's fixed itself, so I can't reproduce the bug to test any theories.

In answer to user277143, no, it didn't match that layout. That was the layout I wanted it to use :) I'd also seen that previous blenderartists.org post when trying to find a solution for this, but it didn't help. Thanks for looking though! I'd had a look too to see if I could find something before I asked here.

In answer to metaphor_set, I can't repro to check now, sorry, but thanks for the suggestion. I'll check if it happens again.